# setup.py install for pylibmc ... error when pip install -r requirements.txt --upgrade --no-cache --no-cache-dir

Tags: python, geonode

When installing the GeoNode 3.2 `requirement.txt` in the virtualenv I get an error. See error below:

**ERROR 1**

```
  Building wheel for pylibmc (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\lenis\Documents\geonode_env\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lenis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9un_vl6h\\pylibmc_b72a11246894401da7f212c10d770cd4\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lenis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9un_vl6h\\pylibmc_b72a11246894401da7f212c10d770cd4\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\lenis\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-avjg7tof'
       cwd: C:\Users\lenis\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9un_vl6h\pylibmc_b72a11246894401da7f212c10d770cd4\
  Complete output (20 lines):
  C:\Users\lenis\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9un_vl6h\pylibmc_b72a11246894401da7f212c10d770cd4\setup.py:98: DeprecationWarning: 'U' mode is deprecated
    with open("README.rst", "U", encoding="utf-8") as r:
  C:\Users\lenis\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9un_vl6h\pylibmc_b72a11246894401da7f212c10d770cd4\setup.py:100: DeprecationWarning: 'U' mode is deprecated
    with open("src/pylibmc-version.h", "U", encoding="utf-8") as r:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pylibmc
  copying src\pylibmc\autoconf.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pylibmc
  copying src\pylibmc\client.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pylibmc
  copying src\pylibmc\consts.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pylibmc
  copying src\pylibmc\pools.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pylibmc
  copying src\pylibmc\test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pylibmc
  copying src\pylibmc\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pylibmc
  copying src\pylibmc\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pylibmc
  running build_ext
  building '_pylibmc' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pylibmc
```

**ERROR 2**

```
Running setup.py install for pylibmc ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\lenis\Documents\geonode_env\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lenis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9un_vl6h\\pylibmc_b72a11246894401da7f212c10d770cd4\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lenis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9un_vl6h\\pylibmc_b72a11246894401da7f212c10d770cd4\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\lenis\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-59thum0c\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\lenis\Documents\geonode_env\include\site\python3.7\pylibmc'
         cwd: C:\Users\lenis\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9un_vl6h\pylibmc_b72a11246894401da7f212c10d770cd4\
    Complete output (20 lines):
    C:\Users\lenis\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9un_vl6h\pylibmc_b72a11246894401da7f212c10d770cd4\setup.py:98: DeprecationWarning: 'U' mode is deprecated
      with open("README.rst", "U", encoding="utf-8") as r:
    C:\Users\lenis\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9un_vl6h\pylibmc_b72a11246894401da7f212c10d770cd4\setup.py:100: DeprecationWarning: 'U' mode is deprecated
      with open("src/pylibmc-version.h", "U", encoding="utf-8") as r:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pylibmc
    copying src\pylibmc\autoconf.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pylibmc
    copying src\pylibmc\client.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pylibmc
    copying src\pylibmc\consts.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pylibmc
    copying src\pylibmc\pools.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pylibmc
    copying src\pylibmc\test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pylibmc
    copying src\pylibmc\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pylibmc
    copying src\pylibmc\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pylibmc
    running build_ext
    building '_pylibmc' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\lenis\Documents\geonode_env\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lenis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9un_vl6h\\pylibmc_b72a11246894401da7f212c10d770cd4\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lenis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9un_vl6h\\pylibmc_b72a11246894401da7f212c10d770cd4\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\lenis\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-59thum0c\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\lenis\Documents\geonode_env\include\site\python3.7\pylibmc' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Comment: I did exactly this, and now running into another error,  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2